# Android - Persist a fragment across many activities

Tags: android, fragment, activity-lifecycle, fragmentmanager

Let's say I have the following:

```
 __________________
|Activity_Parent   |
|        |         |
|        |         | 
|        |         |  
|Fragment_Container|  
|Fragment_Footer   |
|__________________|\
                     \
                      \________________________
                     |      Activity_Child     |
                     |            |            |
                     |            |            |
                     |            |            |
                     |Fragment_Child_Container |
                     |_________________________|
```

Where Activity_Parent hosts a container fragment (with several different screens), and a footer fragment I wish to *persist across all activities* so I do not waste time recreating it - it stays the same for the whole app.

The footer fragment is currently created in the Activity_Parent's onCreate().

When I finish the Activity_Parent and start the Activity_Child (which also recalls the onCreate() of it's parent), is there any way for me to not have to recreate the footer fragment?

I hope I'm clear - getting rather confused myself.